# Insert Text instead of Picture in Word Header

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have several Word documents with a Header. Within this header is a small table with three columns.
In the first column is a small Logo.
In every document I change the Logo in the left column inside the header.
Now I want to replace the Logo with some simple text and I don't get it working.
Here is my code for the replacement of the Logo picture:

```
Sub AutoOpen()

text = "Text to replace"

Dim dd1 As Document: Set dd1 = ActiveDocument
Dim rng1 As Range, seC As Section, an(2) As Long
Dim rngO As Range, rngAN As Range
Dim strToPict As String

strToPict = "C:\Logo.png"

For Each rngO In dd1.StoryRanges

ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageHeader

If rngO.StoryType = wdEvenPagesHeaderStory Then
Set rng1 = rngO.Duplicate
For Each seC In rng1.Sections
    an(0) = seC.Headers(1).Range.InlineShapes(1).Height
    an(1) = seC.Headers(1).Range.InlineShapes(1).Width
    Set rngAN = seC.Headers(1).Range.InlineShapes(1).Range.Duplicate

    seC.Headers(1).Range.InlineShapes(1).Delete
    seC.Headers(1).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:=strToPict, _
    LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, Range:=rngAN

        With seC.Headers(1).Range.InlineShapes(1)
        .Height = 25

        End With
```

How do I replace the existing Logo with the text?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub ReplaceLogoWithText()
   Dim dd1 As Document: Set dd1 = ActiveDocument

   Dim seC As Section

   'If rngO.StoryType = wdEvenPagesHeaderStory Then
   For Each seC In dd1.Sections
      With seC.Headers(wdHeaderFooterEvenPages)
         If .LinkToPrevious = False Then
            With .Range.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range
               If .InlineShapes.Count = 1 Then .InlineShapes(1).Delete
               .Text = "Whatever text you want to insert"
            End With
         End If
      End With
   Next seC
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer but your code does not work. Problem with: With .Range.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range couldn't find the table

Comment: @0x01_PH - Your question indicates that you have a table in your Even Page header. Evidently you don't. You need to check your document and figure out which of the three headers does contain the table and then edit the line `With seC.Headers(wdHeaderFooterEvenPages)` to point to the correct header.

Comment: Sorry I'm a noob in vba. this works perfectly. I just change the wdHeaderFooterEvenPages to wdHeaderFooterPrimary and it works. Thank you so much.